# How to check if vector has element that starts with specific string

Tags: c++

I want to know how to check if vector has element that starts with specific string.

I did that with code below in C#.
But how can I do this in C++.

```
if (Array.Exists(words, word => word.StartsWith("abc")))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exists");
}
```

[Edit]
I tried with code below but I think this is dirty solution when vector is huge.
(My vector has elements over 400000)
Is there a better solution for this?

```
vector<string> words;
bool hasValue = false;

words.push_back("abcdef");
words.push_back("bcdef");
words.push_back("fffewdd");

for (string& word : words)
{
    if (word.find("abc") == 0)
    {
        hasValue = true;

        break;
    }
}

cout << hasValue << endl;
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Look into using [`std::basic_string::rfind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) maybe.

Comment: @Busted, if your code does not work, you can ask for help here. If your code works but you want to find a better or more elegant way of doing it, post a question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Before posting there, make sure to follow that site's [posting guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: You probably want that `cout` inside the if condition otherwise you’re always printing “Exists” regardless of the word actually being in the vector or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more elegent solution can be attained using `<algorithm>`.

```
std::string strToBeSearched = "abc";

bool found = std::any_of(words.begin(), words.end(), [&strToBeSearched](const std::string &s) {
    return s.substr(0, strToBeSearched.size()) == strToBeSearched;
});
```

**Update**:

You may use `find()`also. Something like this:

```
std::string strToBeSearched = "abc";

bool found = std::any_of(words.begin(), words.end(), [&strToBeSearched](const std::string &s) {
    return s.find(strToBeSearched) == 0;
});
```

**Update 2**:

As rightly suggested by [@SidS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9125195/sid-s), you may use `rfind()` also for better performance.

```
std::string strToBeSearched = "abc";

bool found = std::any_of(words.begin(), words.end(), [&strToBeSearched](const std::string &s) {
    return s.rfind(strToBeSearched, 0) == 0;
});
```

Comment: Kudos for using modern language features.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is pretty good.

Using `string::rfind()` is likely to be more efficient, since `string::find()` may search through the whole string :

```
    for (const auto &word : words)
    {
        if (!word.rfind("abc", 0))
        {
            hasValue = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```